# Is CHARSET important for tables with INT only?

Tags: mysql, database-design, character-set, mariadb-10.5

My server default `CHARSET` is `UTF-8` (set in my.cnf). I create tables like

```
CREATE TABLE t1
(
ID int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
Title varchar(255),
PRIMARY KEY(ID)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci KEY_BLOCK_SIZE=2
```

but some tables have only `int` columns. Is it beneficial to use `latin` charset for them? Or is it better to have all tables with `UTF-8` charset for consistency?

```
CREATE TABLE t2
(
ID int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
TagID int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(ID,TagID)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci KEY_BLOCK_SIZE=1
```

**vs.**

```
CREATE TABLE t2
(
ID int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
TagID int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(ID,TagID)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci KEY_BLOCK_SIZE=1
```

Comment: I don't remember ever seeing a table with a `KEY_BLOCK_SIZE` specification.  What is your goal behind it?

Comment: @RickJames it's for the table compression. `KEY_BLOCK_SIZE` is used instead of `ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED` to enhance the compression in accordance with the table structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The character set and collation of a table affects the newly created columns in that table. It also affects char/text columns without a specified character set/collation.

So your `int` only tables don't have any specific difference because of character set, until you add a column that uses it.